# pyqt5 in not responding state when calling the url

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, python-requests, pyqt5

i just implemented a login in pyqt but in between the calling the url and getting the response the qt window is showing the not responding state 
can anyone please suggest me how to avoid not responding state

code:

```
class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, height, width, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((width-size.width())/2, (height-size.height())/2)
        username = QLabel("Username", self)
        username.move(100, 35)
        self.textName = QLineEdit(self)
        password = QLabel("Password", self)
        password.move(100, 110)
        self.textPass = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textPass.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.buttonLogin = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textName)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPass)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)

    def handleLogin(self):
        # TODO: Connect to flask application to check login credentials
        payload = {"username":self.textName.text(),"password":self.textPass.text()}
        print("payload:", payload)
        r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",data=payload)
        print(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
        if r.status_code == 200:
            self.accept()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', 'Bad user or password')
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Use threads:** Tasks that consume a lot of time must be executed in another thread

```
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class LoginWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    logged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def setCredentials(self, username, password):
        self.payload = {"username": username, "password": password}

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def login(self):
        print("payload:", self.payload)
        r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",data=self.payload)
        print(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
        status = r.status_code == 200
        self.logged.emit(status)

class Login(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, height, width, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((width-size.width())/2, (height-size.height())/2)

        username = QtWidgets.QLabel("Username")
        self.textName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        password = QtWidgets.QLabel("Password")
        self.textPass = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.textPass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.buttonLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Login')
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(username, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.textName)
        layout.addWidget(password, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPass)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
        layout.addStretch()

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()
        self.login_worker = LoginWorker()
        self.login_worker.moveToThread(thread)
        
        self.login_worker.logged.connect(self.onLogged)

    def handleLogin(self):
        # TODO: Connect to flask application to check login credentials
        self.login_worker.setCredentials(self.textName.text(), self.textPass.text())
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.login_worker.login)

    def onLogged(self, status):
        if status:
            self.accept()
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', 'Bad user or password')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Login(100, 100)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**2. Use QNAM:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork

class Login(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, height, width, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((width-size.width())/2, (height-size.height())/2)

        username = QtWidgets.QLabel("Username")
        self.textName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        password = QtWidgets.QLabel("Password")
        self.textPass = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.textPass.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.buttonLogin = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Login')
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(username, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.textName)
        layout.addWidget(password, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPass)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
        layout.addStretch()

    def handleLogin(self):
        # TODO: Connect to flask application to check login credentials
        postData = QtCore.QUrlQuery()
        postData.addQueryItem("username", self.textName.text())
        postData.addQueryItem("password", self.textPass.text())
        qnam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/home"
        reply = qnam.post(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)), postData.toString(QtCore.QUrl.FullyEncoded).encode())
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        reply.finished.connect(loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()
        code = reply.attribute(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute)
        if code == 200:
            self.accept()
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', 'Bad user or password')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Login(100, 100)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```